# Error with primary key in one-to-one relationship using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primary-key

I've created a database according to which the user profile is formed by the following two classes:

```
public class Usr
{
    [Key()]
    public int UsrID { get; set; }

    public virtual UsrType UsrType { get; set; }

    public virtual UsrStatus UsrStatus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Email can only contain {0} characters")]
    public string UsrEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32, ErrorMessage = "Password can only contain {0} characters")]
    [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least {0} characters")]
    public string UsrPassword { get; set; }
}

public class UsrDetails
{
    [ForeignKey("UsrID")]
    [Required]
    public virtual Usr Usr { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Name can only contain {0} characters")]
    public string UsrName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Surname can only contain {0} characters")]
    public string UsrSurname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Country can only contain {0} characters")]
    public string UsrCountry { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "City can only contain {0} characters")]
    public string UsrCity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Street can only contain {0} characters")]
    public string UsrStreet { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UsrNum { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UsrPostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

I want to connect them by having both as primary key the `UsrID` and I get an error that `UsrDetails` don't have a primary key because I'm using the foreign key attribute. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [Associations in EF Code First: Part 3 – Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a key property in `UserDetails` with the same name that you declare in the `ForeignKey` attribute:

```
public class UsrDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int UsrID{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsrID")]
    public virtual Usr Usr { get; set; }
}
```

All your entities must have a PK property. In this case where you are representing a one to one relationship, the PK of the dependent entity also is the FK. You can check this [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) in case you need more info.

Comment: @i_ll_be_back, now I noticed this was your first question in SO, congrats!!. If you think my answer was helpful, please, consider accepting my answer by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.There is no obligation to do this.